# How do you return rows from Mysql based on highest value in table column?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, highest

I have a function that is supposed to search the db for the highest 'score'.
The Db is structured like this:

```
----------------------------------------
|  id  |  UrlId  |  Article  |  Score  |
----------------------------------------
```

I can get the highest score correctly, but I do not know how to return the full object based on the highest score.
I am reluctant to loop through the entire table and test the values of 'score' to see which is the highest (although as I type that I suspect I am doing it anyway) because the db will potentially have 10000's of records.
I am sure that this is dead simple, but I have "the dumb and I cant brain today" Does anyone know a more elegant solution?

My end result would have to be something like this:
if there are 4 UrlId;s with the same top score, the user would need to see:

UrlId example1    20(score)

UrlId example2    20(score)

UrlId example3    20(score)

UrlId example4    20(score)

all other results would not be displayed.

```
function gethappiestBlog() {
  $happiestBlogs = /* This is the data that I loop through, this is correct */
  $happinessArray = array();
  foreach($happiestBlogs as $happiestBlog) {
    $happinessArray[]= $happiestBlog->Score;
  }
  $maxHappy = max($happinessArray);
  echo $maxHappy; 
}
```

Comment: Apologies if I used the term "objects" incorrectly, I am still a newbie, hopefully you will understand my meaning

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting to do.  if getting the data from mysql, you can `order by score desc` and `limit 0,1` to get the single row.

Comment: why are you using `exit();` in function??

Comment: @nappingRabbit, Thanks, that is almost exactly what I need, except that "score' is not unique, if there are duplicate highest scores, I need to show all of them.

Comment: @Yogesh Apologies, the exit is used to view the functuion and debug in oir framework, it is not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fieldlist
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `score` = (SELECT MAX(`score`) FROM `tableName`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you use a query?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 ORDER BY score 
  DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you need multiple scores, you could then use a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE score = 
       (SELECT score
          FROM table_name 
         ORDER BY score 
          DESC LIMIT 1;
       );
```

Comment: Thanks but  "score' is not unique, if there are duplicate highest scores, I need to show all of them.

Comment: @user1882752 Please see my answer - it will return the duplicates too.

Comment: ... Why is my answer getting downvoted when it's basically the same thing as the accepted answer?

Comment: @drneel Apologies, its not me who is doing it. I agree that your is very similar and will also work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$dbh=new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY Score DESC");
$stmt->execute();
while($happiestBlog=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):

    echo $happiestBlog->Score;

endwhile;
```

Here `ORDER BY Score DESC` fetch the the row first ehich has highest Score.